# Python: Modifying Excel files while maintaing formatting

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

Is there any way to modify a few cells in an existing Excel file without losing formatting, and without using xlutils?

I have access to xlwt, and xlrd, but not xlutils.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what kind of formatting do you want to keep. E.g. if it's conditional formatting - you'll lose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its use is deprecated nowadays, you can use from win32com.client module which contains "dispatch". It preserves formatting.
Example :

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible=1
book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("FileName")
sheet1 = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value="ABC"
```